# Nested foreach loop with pointers?

Tags: c++, stl

```
map<string, vector<int>*> settings
for (auto el : settings)
    {
        for(auto i : el)
        {
            cout << i;
        }
    }
```

I get with inside el : this range-based 'for' statement require a suitable begin function and none was found.
How can I fix that?

Comment: `for (auto i : el.second)`?

Comment: Each map entry has a pointer to a vector (which is a questionable design, consider a smart pointer), so you actually need `for( auto i : *(el.second) )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use

```
map<string, vector<int>*> settings
for (auto el : settings)
{
}
```

`el` is a `std::pair<const string, vector<int>*>`. Check out the definition of `std::map::value_type` at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

To get the items from the vector, you'll need to use

```
map<string, vector<int>*> settings
for (auto el : settings)
{
   for ( auto item : *(el.second) )
   {
       // Use item
   }
}
```

To avoid unnecessary copying of the `std::pair`, you can use `auto const& el`.

```
map<string, vector<int>*> settings
for (auto const& el : settings)
{
   for ( auto item : *(el.second) )
   {
       // Use item
   }
}
```

Comment: `el` should be (const) reference, no reason to copy that data

Comment: @Slava, makes sense.